# cant access process.env varibales inside node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

apply-platform

- env-bundle
- node_modules

  - node-client

I have a repo apply-platform that has env variables and node modules, in the node module there is another repo node-client.
When I try to access process.env variables inside node-client project I get following object as process.env

```
{
  \"LANG\":\"en_US.UTF-8\",\"PATH\":\"/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin\",\"HOME\":\"/home/ubuntu\",\"LOGNAME\":\"ubuntu\",\"USER\":\"ubuntu\",\"SHELL\":\"/bin/bash\",\"PM2_USAGE\":\"CLI\",\"PM2_HOME\":\"/home/ubuntu/.pm2\",\"SILENT\":\"true\",\"env_production\":\"[object Object]\",\"instance_var\":\"NODE_APP_INSTANCE\",\"exec_mode\":\"cluster_mode\",\"env\":\"[object Object]\",\"treekill\":\"true\",\"autorestart\":\"true\",\"automation\":\"true\",\"pmx\":\"true\",\"vizion\":\"true\",\"merge_logs\":\"true\",\"cwd\":\"/srv/cbax-apply-platform/\",\"log_type\":\"json\",\"instances\":\"4\",\"name\":\"www\",\"node_args\":\"\",\"pm_exec_path\":\"/srv/cbax-apply-platform/server.js\",\"pm_cwd\":\"/srv/cbax-apply-platform\",\"exec_interpreter\":\"node\",\"pm_out_log_path\":\"/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/application.log\",\"pm_err_log_path\":\"/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/application.log\",\"pm_pid_path\":\"/home/ubuntu/.pm2/pids/www-13.pid\",\"km_link\":\"false\",\"vizion_running\":\"false\",\"NODE_APP_INSTANCE\":\"0\",\"PM2_JSON_PROCESSING\":\"true\",\"_\":\"/usr/bin/pm2\",\"XDG_DATA_DIRS\":\"/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop\",\"SHLVL\":\"1\",\"PWD\":\"/srv/cbax-apply-platform/\",\"PORT\":\"8080\",\"NODE_ENV\":\"test\",\"REGION\":\"USEastTest\",\"www\":\"{}\",\"status\":\"launching\",\"pm_uptime\":\"1629364026293\",\"axm_actions\":\"\",\"axm_monitor\":\"[object Object]\",\"axm_options\":\"[object Object]\",\"axm_dynamic\":\"[object Object]\",\"created_at\":\"1629364026181\",\"pm_id\":\"13\",\"restart_time\":\"10\",\"unstable_restarts\":\"0\",\"_pm2_version\":\"2.6.1\",\"versioning\":\"null\",\"node_version\":\"9.11.1\",\"exit_code\":\"0\"}
```

1. How can I access process.env variables inside the node-module (node-client)
2. I tried console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env.env)) it still gives me [object][object] as output;
3. I found this object comes from ecosystem.config.js file of apply-platform , so added these 2 variables and pushed it to the server, but when I console process.env i cant see these 2 variables in node-client

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse() ? --> the variable is env: "[object Object]" so you have a string with that content. Might be a problem on how that output is produced

Comment: no it gives unexpected token o on parsing @malarres

Comment: Are you trying to add the process.env.env object to the environment variables using node? I think your issue isn't with reading the variable but rather with when it is written. But I think it is a bit vague what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The Node injects the process.env global variable at runtime in our app to use, and it represents the state of the system environment of our app when it starts. So, for example, if the system has the PATH variable set, this will be accessible to you through the process.env.PATH variable you can use to check where binaries are located and make external calls to them if required.

When we write the code, we can never be sure where our app can be deployed. If we require the database in development, we spin up the instance of it, and we link to it via a connection string , something like 127.0.0.1:3306. However, when deploying it to the server in production, we might need to link it to the remote server, 32.22.2.1.

Accessing environment variables in Node.js is supported out of the box. When your Node.js process boots up, it will automatically provide access to all the existing environment variables by creating the env object as a property of the process global object.

**Explicitly loading variables from the .env file.**

npm install dotenv --save

Afterward, add the following line to the very top of your entry file (index.js or app.js).

require('dotenv').config();

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm module that loads environment variables from `.env` files into `process.env`, called `dotenv`. In your case, you would use it like this:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config({ path: "/path/to/.env/"})
```

You could then access the environment variables in Node.js like this:

```
process.env.MYVAR
```

If you don't want the variables specified in the `.env` file to mangle with other environment variables, you can also do this:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from("PORT=3000") //example
const env = dotenv.parse(buffer) // returns object -> { PORT: 3000 }
// env.PORT would return 3000
```

`dotenv.parse` accepts a buffer object and returns an object, instead of binding it to `process.env`. You could also use the `fs` module to read the contents of the `.env` file, and pass it to `dotenv.parse`.

To learn more, reference the npm page for dotenv:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv